# Zooming with PDFBox

Tags: java, swing, pdfbox

Does PDFBox support some sort of zoom function? I'm currently outputting pages to Images at the moment but this is quite slow especially when the document has to be resized.

Answer (score 1):

```
PDPageXYZDestination dest = new PDPageXYZDestination();    
dest.setPageNumber(0);    
dest.setZoom(1);    
dest.setTop(new Float(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A4.getHeight()).intValue());    
PDActionGoTo action = new PDActionGoTo();    
action.setDestination(dest);    
doc.getDocumentCatalog().setOpenAction(action);
```